# How to use models without database on CakePHP and have associations?

Tags: cakephp

I've got the field `country_id` in one of my models and instead of creating a `countries` table which contains a list of countries that doesn't change, what's the best approach to this?

I'm thinking about using a model without a database table but I don't know how to implement this.

Please help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would suggest using `ArraySource` from the community-maintained CakePHP [Datasources plugin](https://github.com/cakephp/datasources):

- CakePHP 1.3.x - see [`master` branch](https://github.com/cakephp/datasources/blob/master/models/datasources/array_source.php)
- CakePHP 2.x - see [`2.0` branch](https://github.com/cakephp/datasources/blob/2.0/Model/Datasource/ArraySource.php)

Download the entire plugin and extract the contents to `app/plugins/datasources`.

Define a connection to the datasource in `app/config/database.php`:

```
public $array = array('datasource' => 'Datasources.array');
```

This should allow you to emulate a table by defining records in your model:

```
class Country extends AppModel {

    public $useDbConfig = 'array';

    public $records = array(
        array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'Test record')
    );

}
```

Comment: Beyond the repository's [readme file](https://github.com/cakephp/datasources#readme), the only other documentation is in the docblocks for a couple of datasources ([amazon](https://github.com/cakephp/datasources/blob/c8da44d638c9fa5c9baada7ead7f366bdb1d03e1/models/datasources/amazon_associates_source.php#L22)|[csv](https://github.com/cakephp/datasources/blob/c8da44d638c9fa5c9baada7ead7f366bdb1d03e1/models/datasources/csv_source.php#L22)). To find configuration options for each datasource, look for `_baseConfig` or instances of "config". More docs in the code would be a definite improvement.

Comment: definitly a nice approach. didnt know about that one yet. will check it out. I used to do this this way until now: http://www.dereuromark.de/2010/06/24/static-enums-or-semihardcoded-attributes/

Answer (score 15):

you can totaly use the no table syntax:

```
class ModelWithoutTable extends AppModel
{
    var $useTable = false;
}
```

to have this Country Model tableless, but you need to mock a data source (i.e. XML,YAML,PHP Array and etc) for the countries data.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks.. Worked like charm. :)

Answer (score 1):

As alternative, if there's no other data attached to the country besides, basically, an id of what country it is, you can probably keep it within the same model without association. Something along the lines of:

```
class MyModel extends AppModel {

    public static $countries = array(
        'Africa', 'America', ..., 'Zululand'
    );

    public $validate = array(
        'country' => array(
            'rule' => array('inList', self::$countries),
            ...
        )
    )

}
```

Comment: I've never been to the country 'Africa' ;)