# cakephp - manually create records for model without a table

Tags: cakephp, model, datasource

I need several models, but since the data size is not more than 5 records each, it seems like a waste to use db-table.
how should I do it?

these models are supposed to be linked to other models

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sounds like some kind of enum to me.
if it is (does not change very much or does not need a frontend to add/edit/delete) you can put it in the model code and use sth like
http://www.dereuromark.de/2010/06/24/static-enums-or-semihardcoded-attributes/

if you need to have a crud backend for it to edit it online you could group them together to a model maybe called "list_items" with a "type" field to distinguish the different models you are talking about. this way you have one model holding all those enums and you can provide add/edit/delete access for them for users/admins.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [array datasource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6924574/how-to-use-models-without-database-on-cakephp-and-have-associations/6924783#6924783) One advantage of it is you can treat it like a model (linking to other models, do find() query, etc.)