# Cakephp - Convert numerical DB value into string for display

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a Classroom model, which has an INT field called level. The values for this field can range from 1-7. What I would like to do is translate the integer in that field into a String for display, according to a predetermined legend, such as this:

```
1 - Basic I
2 - Basic II
3 - Basic III
4 - Intermediate I
```

etc... What would be the best way of achieving this? Using `afterFind()`?

Thanks

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6924574/how-to-use-models-without-database-on-cakephp-and-have-associations

Comment: Can I create associations to an ArraySource model? It doesn't seem to work :S

Answer (score 2):

Why not make an extra table containing strings matching the ID of the INT field called level.
Get the string from that table using the matching ID and your good to go.

Comment: yeap I could definitely do that.

Answer (score 0):

the quickest way (if the strings do not change much!):

http://www.dereuromark.de/2010/06/24/static-enums-or-semihardcoded-attributes/

```
echo Classroom::levels($classroom['Classroom']['level']);
```

in the view - whereever you need it

it also uses less resources than any other approach (therefor is the fastest).