# CakePHP: how do I provide hard coded data for a model instead of a table to provide it?

Tags: cakephp, model

I presently have a model called UserLevels which defines some user levels (user, premium user, admin, etc) and some properties of them (number, description, color, etc).

I've decided I would rather hard code this, and be able to use the __() method on the names and descriptions.

How do I go about providing data to a model so that it doesn't use a database?  Is there a better way to approach this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update: Full multi-field records in a model without a database**

After the author made his goal more clear, this should be the solution:

[How to use models without database on CakePHP and have associations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6924574/how-to-use-models-without-database-on-cakephp-and-have-associations)

Don't get the title wrong, read it first, the answer describes exactly what would  be the solution here as well.

**Solution for single field, enum like data:**

If you don't use a DB table and entries are limited it is always good to use constants because you can't do a typo without causing an error somewhere and UserLevel::USER is much more clear than a random 'user' string somewhere that could mean anything.

```
class UserLevel extends AppModel {

    public $useTable = false;

    const ADMIN = 'admin';
    const USER = 'user';
    /* ... */

    public function getUserLevels() {
        return [
            UserLevel::ADMIN => __('Admin'),
            /* ... */
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your feedback.  There are more to these levels than just names though (I should have been more clear... that's what I meant when I said "and some properties").  They have numeric values, descriptions, colors, etc.  So I'm looking at an array of data for each level.

Comment: You could use static properties instead of constants.  You don't get the protection against overwrites that a constant provides, but you get flexibility with data types.

Comment: Well, why are you not using a database table in this case then if they have all of these things. There is really no reason to not do so IMHO.

Comment: @ScottHarwell - that would work.  However, I would lose the benefit of cake's magic with associations.  Is there a way to provide data to a model not connected to the db?

Comment: @burzum - I understand your opinion, however I respectfully disagree.  Hard coding it makes it more tamper proof, allows me to use the translation function, and saves unnecessary calls to the database.  :)

Comment: You can translate DB content as well. Either in afterFind() by passing a value into __() or by using the translate behavior. However, see my update on the question.

Comment: I should be more clear: I can use the translation function, and build the translation files from it without needing the database content.

I appreciate the solution you provided... I am working within a plugin now though.  Can I place a plugin inside of a plugin?